What is correct way of passing multiple named arguments to riverpod provider
I want to pass multiple arguments to a riverpod provider and make network requests accordingly as below
@riverpod
class FetchProducts extends _$FetchProducts {
  @override
  Future<List<Product>> build({
    required String? specificProductId,
    required String? clientUid,
  }) async {
    if (specificProductId != null) {
      // Network request-1
    }
    } else if (clientUid != null && clientUid != '') {
      // Network request-2
    }
    else {
      // Network request-3
    }
}

Console shows below when it is initialized first with both parameters null (i.e. Network request-3 would have run). Note the null in the parenthesis for arguments.

Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#6e9e5(null) was
initialized with AsyncLoading<List>()

When another widget makes another network request with a non-null clientUID (i.e. Network request-2) below is what we get in console. Note the null in the place of arguments.

Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#0eacb(null) was
initialized with AsyncLoading<List>() Provider
fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#6e9e5(null) was disposed

Please suggest correct way of passing multiple arguments to riverpod provider so that both the network requests with different arguments are cached and not disposed.

Use the generator, and then your build method for a class can have as many family args as you want.

You can use FutureProviderFamily as below :
First method :
Create the custom argument :
// Argument
class FetchProductsArgument {
  final String? specificProductId;
  final String? clientUid;

  const FetchProductsArgument({
    required this.specificProductId,
    required this.clientUid,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is FetchProductsArgument &&
        other.specificProductId == specificProductId &&
        other.clientUid == clientUid;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(runtimeType, specificProductId, clientUid);
}

Then create the provider (at the top level of the file) :
final fetchProducts = FutureProviderFamily<List<String>, FetchProductsArgument>(
  (ref, arg) async {
    if (arg.specificProductId != null) {
      // Network request-1
    } else if (arg.clientUid != null && arg.clientUid != '') {
      // Network request-2
    } else {
      // Network request-3
    }
  },
);

Second method :
Use riverpod-generator (at the top level of the file):
@riverpod
Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts({
  required String? specificProductId,
  required String?  clientUid,
}) async {
  if (specificProductId != null) {
    // Network request-1
  } else if (clientUid != null && clientUid != '') {
    // Network request-2
  } else {
    // Network request-3
  }
}


Ok, so instantiate this FetchProductsArgument class and use this in the second method to pass variables ? how ? I checked that riverpod is initializing the provider twice with same #6e9e5 value one when clientUid is null in the first widget and when clientUid is non-null but empty ('') in second widget. How to check if one of the providers with #6e9e5 is alive after I get a disposed message in console?

Well,   print('All products list provider exists?: ${ref.exists(fetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: null))}'); shows true after disposed message in console. And to be specific I get provider disposed message when I choose a client from DropDown in the widget with following provider. final AsyncValue<List<Product>> productsProvider =         ref.watch(FetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.clientUid));
